# Table relationship - multiple HABTM or multiple hasMany

Tags: database, cakephp, relationship, has-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a table `files` and it belongs to one either `post`, `article`, `notion` or `paragrah`. Maybe in the future, there will be more.

What relationship do you suggest to use? Multiple HABTM tables, or multiple columns (`post_id`, `aticle_id`,...)?

Or maybe two columns `parent_alias` and `parent_id`? But how to easily work with this in CakePHP?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this case can be solved using hasOne

just add one type column (varchar) and one foregin_key (integer) in your files table

and bind this model in your post, article ... models using hasOne relation

for post

```
$hasOne = array('File' => array('foreignKey'=>'foreign_key','conditions'=>array('type'=>'post')))
```

in article

```
$hasOne = array('File' => array('foreignKey'=>'foreign_key','conditions'=>array('type'=>'article')))
```

Just make sure you update 'type' column while saving association

Comment: Great, thanks! I was just wondering if something like you wrote is possible. I have to use $hasMany, but that doesn't really matter. :)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot choose for you. It depends of your data.

The question is: can a file belong to several posts?

If yes you'll need a HABTM.

If no BelongsTo will suffice.